# How to override the state of a Riverpod StateNotifier for testing

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider, riverpod

I want to override my `StateNotifierProvider` state manually for testing. Overriding providers can be done using `ProviderContainer` or `ProviderScope`. But it only gives the option to override the notifier, not the state.

My question is how should I override the state?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to override the providers. For instance, when you want to test a specific category. In this case, we can override the ScopedProvider with a value. Then, in the ProviderScope, we can choose which provider to override and choose which value to override

```
testWidgets('Override the current scope', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(ProviderScope(
        overrides: [
          selectedCategory.state.overrideWithValue(Category("Pear", Colors.green))
        ],
        child: HookBuilder(builder: (context) {
          return MaterialApp(home: CategoryWidget());
        })));

    expect((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Text)) as Text).style.color,
        Colors.green);
    expect((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Text)) as Text).data, "Pear");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Adding a function to every StateNotifierProvider just for testing is a lot of unnecessary work. Also, it may lead to misusing that function. I'm looking for a way without adding anything to existing providers.

Comment: The issue is with `StateNotifierProvider`. `overrideWithValue` only allows `Notifiers` as value. Can't override the state.

Comment: this article  helped me may it help you https://bartvwezel.nl/flutter/flutter-riverpod-testing-example/

Comment: I am also having this issue, I cannot find a way to override the state of a StateNotifierProvider which returns a class that extends StateNotifier<T>. The only override available is .notifier. I have posted an example of my code and state architecture here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011054/riverpod-testing-how-to-mock-state-with-statenotifierprovider