# How to mock a StateNotifier in flutter / Riverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-riverpod, flutter-mockito

I wrote a simple provider in flutter that should provide the current date/time (clock.now() is from the clock package):

```
final clockProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Clock, DateTime>((ref) {
  return Clock();
});

class Clock extends StateNotifier<DateTime> {
  late final Timer _timer;
  Clock() : super(clock.now()) {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      state = clock.now();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

One reason for that is that I thought it would be easier this way to test with a given set time using Mockito:

```
@GenerateNiceMocks([
  MockSpec<Clock>(),
])

void main() {
    testWidgets(
        "test clock", (tester) async {

      // arrange
      final MockClock mockClock = MockClock();
      when(mockClock.state).thenReturn(DateTime(2000));
      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          clockProvider.overrideWithValue(mockClock),
        ],
      );
      await container.pump();
      final result = container.read(clockProvider);
    });
```

This throws the following exception:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderException was thrown running a test:
An exception was thrown while building StateNotifierProvider<Clock, DateTime>#0cdfd.

Thrown exception:
Bad state: Tried to read the state of an uninitialized provider
```

When following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011054/riverpod-testing-how-to-mock-state-with-statenotifierprovider) and overwriting not with a value but with a provider the error message is the same and flutter still complains about "Tried to read the state of an uninitialized provider":

```
      final MockClock mockClock = MockClock();
      when(mockClock.state).thenReturn(DateTime(2000));
      final mockClockProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Clock, DateTime>((ref) {
        return mockClock;
      });
      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          clockProvider.overrideWithProvider(mockClockProvider),
        ],
      );
```

Would appreciate any help in finding the mistake!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Riverpod Testing: How to mock state with StateNotifierProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011054/riverpod-testing-how-to-mock-state-with-statenotifierprovider)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz In the example the mockProvider returns an actual counter object. In my case I would like to also mock the State it returns (fixed DateTime instead of now()). I think this is where it breaks.

Comment: @Olf, I have the same issue. but since even Riverpod says, we should mock the repositories instead of the Controllers/States, I think they don't support this out of the box. I am still hoping for someone creating a small package that takes care of it. I think mocking the Controllers is a cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test with a given time, [the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011054/riverpod-testing-how-to-mock-state-with-statenotifierprovider) you linked basically does this by providing arguments for your constructor.
In your case it would be something like

```
class ClockNotifier extends StateNotifier<DateTime> {
  late final Timer _timer;
  ClockNotifier(Clock clock = clock.now()) : super(clock) {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      state = clock.now();
    });
  }
```

Note: Doing `state = clock.now();` in the `Timer.periodic()` would override everything you set in the constructor. But it might not effect it for your test.

Second note: you should rename it to ClockNotifier as you are using the Clock package

I hope that helps, I am doing Flutter only since a few month now.